# Does .Net have Enumerations that map to SqlServers sysschedules values?

Tags: .net, sql-server, job-scheduling

We are writing a scheduling system and are planning to mimic the [sysschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx) table in SqlServer.

We have been looking to see if the .Net Framework has these enumerations already, or if we have to create them ourselves.

We haven't found them...but that doesn't mean they aren't there.

Does anybody know if they exist?  I'd rather not duplicate the effort if it already exists.

Comment: Have you looked at SQL-DMO?

Comment: @Dustin - SMO these days. It's been renamed.

Comment: @Oded - You are correct, i forget that Microsoft like to rename things often...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms162169.aspx) (SMO) is a set of managed libraries that deal with SQL Server management.

These contain classes, enumeration and other object that allow full control of SQL Server instances and servers.

In this instance, the [`JobSchedule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobschedule.aspx) class look like what you need.

Comment: Thanks, bringing in all of SMO for the enums is a bit much since we're not actually scheduling in Sql Server, just following the structure.  Going to use it as a reference to create our own enums anyhow.